# iOS Warning: Semantic Issue (Multiple methods named 'setDelegate:' found)

Tags: objective-c, ios, segue

I'm new to iOS 5 and having an issue with delegates and segues.

I have a main view controller that segues to a `SettingsViewController`. I make the main VC the delegate of the Settings VC with this code:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SETTINGS"]) {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

The `SettingViewController` then segues to multiple option screens. I was trying to make the `SettingsViewController` the delegate for those option screens, but I get the warning that the `setDelegate:` method was found in two places (the `MainViewController`, and the `SettingsViewController`).

How best to resolve this issue? Thanks!

P.S. I've discovered I only get this warning when I enable Strict Selector Matching warnings in the compiler settings (on the advice of a tutorial book). Leave it off? Fix the problem? I'm not really sure...

Comment: Leave that warning off. It's not helpful. If you really want it on, you can suppress the warning by casting the results of `[segue destinationViewController]` to the appropriate type.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. Can you give me an example of casting? I've heard the term but am not quite sure what it would look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be sufficient to cast the view controller to the known type:

```
[(SettingsViewController *)[segue destinationViewController] setDelegate:self];
```